# Counting countable objects using count

Tags: php

Listing a link from PHP's documentation [Countable::count](http://php.net/manual/en/countable.count.php), how does the first example works?

```
<?php
class myCounter implements Countable {
    private $count = 0;
    public function count() {
        return ++$this->count;
    }
}

$counter = new myCounter;

for($i=0; $i<10; ++$i) {
    echo "I have been count()ed " . count($counter) . " times\n";
}
```

Is it possible for the function `count` to access the `private` field `$count` in the class `myCounter`, and how?

Comment: The `count()` function returns the amount of times. So not really.

Comment: Can you clarify which function you refer to when you say "the function `count`" - do you mean the function contained within `myCounter`, or do you mean [the PHP function, `count`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php)?  One has access to `$count`, the other doesn't...

Comment: The method is executed when using the `count()` function on an object implementing Countable.

Comment: I suppose you wanted to do `$counter->count()`, right?

Comment: From your own link: "This method is executed when using the count() function on an object implementing Countable.". You could just call `$counter->count()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The PHP `count` function is not accessing the private `$count`. What is actually happening is this:

1. `count` (the PHP function) is called with the argument `$counter`
2. The function tests if `$counter` is an array, it isn't. It checks if `$counter` implements the interface `Countable`.
3. Because `$counter` does implement the interface `Countable`, it has a public method `count` (separate from the PHP function).
4. PHP calls `$counter->count()`, then returns its result.

As you can see, there was no mention of the private `$count`. The public `count` method can do whatever a regular class method can – including accessing the instance's private variables. Consider this:

```
class myCounter implements Countable {
    public function count() {
        return 42;
    }
}

$counter = new myCounter;
echo "I have " . count($counter) . " items.";
```

Which would result in:

```
I have 42 items.
```

Answer (score 2):

The php function `count(arg)` accept as argument an array or a Countable object. A Countable is an instance of a Class that implements the Countable interface: it means that it must have a `count` method that returns an integer number. How you implement it, it's up to you. You can keep the count with a variable like in the example, or you can return a random number, or whatever you want.  So to answer your question, no the count() function does not access the private field $count, but it calls the count method implemented by the class.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a basic example that is just incrementing a variable everytime count is run. You could easily swap this out with something like:

```
class Repository implements Countable {
    private $data = [];
    public function count() {
        return count($this->data);
    }
}
```

This is another example of a repository that contains records in the `$data` property.  Using `count($instanceOfRepository)` will return the count of `$data`.

Answer (score 1):

`count` function doesn't access `private` field `$count` in your class. It calls `public` method `count` described in the `Countable` interface.

This particular example is a little bit weird because it actually counts how many times `count` function was called and it might confuse the reader.